# Multipart POST works from Postman but not from Angular Http Client

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot, http, postman

I'm trying to upload a google maps-like review that has some content and optional images attached to it.

I've tried it first in Postman and it seems to work great, however I'm having a lot of trouble sending the same request in Angular.

This is the postman request (it has default Headers with Content-Type: multipart/form-data):
[image]

And this is the angular service that tries to make the same request with form-data:

```
  addMultipart(review: Review, files: FileList): Observable<Review> {
    const formData = new FormData();
    for (let i = 0; i < files?.length || 0; i++)
      formData.append('files', files[i]);

    formData.append('review', JSON.stringify(review));

    let opts = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        // 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': '*/*',
      }),
    };

    return this.http
      .post<Review>(this.url, formData, opts)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError<Review>()));
  }
```

Now, if the request `content-type` is `application/json` like in the code above,
I get an error that says `Required String parameter 'review' is not present`, even though the
payload contains form-data with name `review`
[image]

And if I set `content-type` to `multipart/form-data` like in Postman, I get the CORS error:
[image]

I'm honestly pretty clueless about what's causing this error so any help is greatly appreciated! :D

Comment: you need to set cors policy in your server

Comment: It turns out that removing the Content-Type header altogether seems to work.

Comment: Thanks @95xxxtent. The tip has really helped. As far as I see this, the multipart form data content type header with boundary is added by the angular http client automatically. So if we set the content type explicitly, it breaks the boundary addition. So just removing the Content-Type header for the upload endpoint fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

to fix CORS error in develop environment :  you can install the Allow-Control-Allow-Origin plugin
The quickest fix you can make is to install the moesif CORS extension . Once installed, click it install the Allow-Control-Allow-Origin plugin
The quickest fix you can make is to install the moesif CORS extension . Once installed, click it in your browser to activate the extension. Make sure the icon’s label goes from “off”: your browser to activate the extension. Make sure the icon’s label goes from “off”:

to fix that in production environment : [this is good article](https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9)